# How to scroll Qt widgets by keyboard?

Tags: python, qt, pyside

This is a portion of a Python class that I wrote:

```py
    def keyPressEvent(self, event):
        if event.text() == 'n':
            self.widget.scroll(0, -self.height())
        elif event.text() == 'p':
            self.widget.scroll(0, self.height())
```

When the user presses `n`, the widget `widget` (which has a scrollbar), will scroll downwards by `self.height()` pixels (which is the entire height of the window; i.e. next page).  Opposite is when `p` is pressed: returns to previous page.

But the problem is that:

- Usually, a proper scroller will stop when it reaches page's top.  But pressing `p` will keep going backwards towards infinity in the back, where there is an indefinitely deep void of nothingness!
- Opposite is true for `n`; jumps into some unseen abyss into the distant future, beyond the communication horizon.

***Question.*** How to make a *proper* scroller using keyboard bindings?  A proper scroller is one where it saturates at page's boundaries.

---

### Appendix

This is more code (still trimmed to be readable).  My goal here is to show what kind of widgets I am using to address a question in a comment.

```py
#!/usr/bin/python3

import sys
import random

try:
    from PySide6 import QtCore, QtWidgets
except ModuleNotFoundError:
    from PySide2 import QtCore, QtWidgets

# ... <omitted for brevity> ...

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        # create ui's elements
        self.scroll = QtWidgets.QScrollArea()
        self.widget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.hbox   = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()

        # link ui's elements
        self.setCentralWidget(self.scroll)
        self.scroll.setWidget(self.widget)
        self.widget.setLayout(self.hbox)

        # configure ui's elements
        self.scroll.setWidgetResizable(True)
        self.scroll.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(
            QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarPolicy.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
        self.scroll.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(
            QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarPolicy.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)

        self.columns = []
        self.add_column()

        self.show()

    # ... <omitted for brevity> ...


    def add_column(self):
        # ... <omitted for brevity> ...

    # ... <omitted for brevity> ...

    def keyPressEvent(self, event):
        # ... <omitted for brevity> ...
        if event.text() == c['key_next_page']:
            self.widget.scroll(0, -self.height())
        elif event.text() == c['key_prev_page']:
            self.widget.scroll(0, self.height())

    # ... <omitted for brevity> ...
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity, is there a specific reason for not using QScrollArea?

Comment: @musicamante - I added extra code in appendix.  The only reason to any retard behaiour is that I'm new.  I am already using `QScrollArea`, but I guess somehow you concluded that I am not using it, perhaps because I'm using some odd API instead?  Kindly tell me what's in your mind; I am probably doing something wrong _(also any other suggestions are also highly appreciated as this is my 1st Qt app)_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `scroll()` function rarely needs to be directly used.

QScrollBar already calls it *internally*, by overriding the virtual function of its inherited class (QAbstractScrollArea), [`scrollContentsBy()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractscrollarea.html#scrollContentsBy). As the documentation says:

> Calling this function in order to scroll programmatically is an error, use the scroll bars instead (e.g. by calling QScrollBar::setValue() directly).

So, the solution is usually quite simple: instead of scrolling the widget, set the value of the scroll bar. Note that this will *always* work, even when scroll bars are hidden.

Before providing the final code, please note two aspects:

- when checking for keys, it's usually better to use the [key enumeration](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html#Key-enum) instead of the `text()` value of the key event; there are many reasons for this, but, most importantly, it's related to the fact that "keys" are usually mapped to *numeric* values, and using the actual internal value is generally more accurate and reliable than comparing strings;
- you shall not override the `keyPressEvent()` of the parent (unless you really know what you're doing and why): if the parent has other widgets that only handle certain keys but *not* what you're looking for, you may end up in scrolling the area for the wrong reason; suppose you have complex layout that also has a QSpinBox *outside* of the scroll area: that control doesn't generally handle the <kbd>P</kbd> key, but the user might press it by mistake (trying to press <kbd>0</kbd>), and they'll see an unexpected behavior: they typed the wrong key, and another, unrelated widget got scrolled;

The solution is to subclass QScrollArea and override its `keyPressEvent()` instead, then set the value of the scroll bar using its [`pageStep()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractslider.html#pageStep-prop) property (which, for QScrollArea, equals to the width or height of the scrolled widget).

```py
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets

class KeyboardScrollArea(QtWidgets.QScrollArea):
    def keyPressEvent(self, event):
        if event.key() in (QtCore.Qt.Key_N, QtCore.Qt.Key_P):
            sb = self.verticalScrollBar()
            if (event.key() == QtCore.Qt.Key_P 
                and sb.value() > 0):
                    sb.setValue(sb.value() - sb.pageStep())
                    return
            elif (event.key() == QtCore.Qt.Key_N 
                and sb.value() < sb.maximum()):
                    sb.setValue(sb.value() + sb.pageStep())
                    return
        super().keyPressEvent(event)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
    scroll = KeyboardScrollArea()
    widget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
    scroll.setWidget(widget)
    scroll.setWidgetResizable(True)
    layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(widget)
    for i in range(50):
        layout.addWidget(QtWidgets.QPushButton(str(i + 1)))
    scroll.show()
    app.exec_()
```

Note that I explicitly checked that the scroll bar value was greater than 0 (for "page up") and lass then the maximum. That is because when an event is not handled, it should normally be *propagated* to the parent. Suppose you have a custom scroll area *inside* another custom scroll area: you may want to be able to keep moving up/down the *outer* scroll area whenever the *inner* one cannot scroll any more.

Another possibility is to install an *event filter* on the scroll area, and listen for `KeyPress` events, then do the same as above (and, in that case, `return True` when the scroll actually happens). The concept is basically the same, the difference is that you don't need to subclass the scroll area (but a subclass will still be required, as the event filter must override [`eventFilter()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#eventFilter)).

Comment: Great help, thanks a lot.  I have 2 arguments that I'd like to share to hear your thoughts on them:  **(1)** this app is going to have a vim-like UI; i.e. mode-based.  So, because of this, I think I have to handle all key presses globally.  **(2)** As for supplying keys literally vs. library's enumeration, is because this is chosen via the configuration by the end-user, and users probably dislike writing Qt eumerations in their configuration files -- Are these reasonable explanations?

Comment: @caveman 1. then, my explanation sustains even more what I wrote: you have to be *extremely* careful with how you handle key events: they are *always* sent to the widget that accepts input focus, and unless you are extremely sure about the behavior of those widgets, you cannot implement your solution properly (consider my example about the spin box); 2. using enums doesn't force their usage on the UI, it's up to you to *properly* implement their "translation". Eventually consider [QKeySequenceEdit](//doc.qt.io/qt-5/qkeysequenceedit.html).