# How to avoid over-packing non-srolling Qt layouts?

Tags: qt, pyside

A Qt packing layout, such as `QVBoxLayout`, can pack widgets inside it, such as buttons.  In this case, they will be packed vertically as shown in image below:

[image]

When we pack *too many* widgets inside such a layout, and since scrolling is not added by default, the buttons will eventually get squeezed onto each other up to a point that they will overlap, as shown below:

[image]

***My questions are:***

1. How to tell Qt to not show/pack widgets beyond the available viewing space in the non-scrolling layout?
2. How to handle the case when the window is resized?  I.e. Qt should add/remove widgets accordingly.  E.g. if there is extra space available, then perhaps Qt should add some extra widgets that it couldn't add previously.

To be specific:  "too many packed widgets" is when the widgets start invading spaces of other widgets, including their inter-widget spacings or margins.

---

### Appendix

Images above are generated by this code below as run in a tile in [i3](https://i3wm.org), which is a modified version of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72843580/5810023).

```py
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets

app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
widget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(widget)
for i in range(40):
    layout.addWidget(QtWidgets.QPushButton(str(i + 1)))
widget.show()
app.exec_()
```

When too many widgets are packed:

- If the window is tiled, you see them overcrowded as in in the image.
- If the window is floating, the window will keep growing until it is no longer fully visible in the monitor.

None of these outcomes are acceptable in my case.  My goal is to have Qt only pack as much as will be visible, and add/remove/hide/show dynamically as the window gets resized.

Comment: *"How to tell Qt to not show/pack widgets beyond the available viewing space in the non-scrolling layout?"* So what do you want to happen instead?

Comment: I think your best bet would be to use QScrollArea, and hide/show widgets so that none are outside the visible viewport. To be clear, this is not a feature provided by Qt OOTB.

Comment: @hyde - to have Qt not show/pack those extra widgets to avoid overcrowding the area.  When the window becomes larger, it may pack some more accordingly.  But never pack beyond the limit

Comment: If you're ok with just clipping (some widgets would then be partially shown), have your top level widget not contain a layout, but instead have 1 intermediate widget at (0,0) position. Set that widgets size to its own size hint, and have your actual widgets inside it in a layout as usual.

Comment: Clipping is not acceptable in my scenario.  I.e. what is shown must be fully, and properly, shown (without overcrowding).

Comment: I'd suggest making the clipping verson first. Then adding code to show fully visible widgets, and hide those that are outside area of the outermost widget.

Comment: Making a custom layout would be one option, too. Check Qt examples

Comment: Again, use QScrollArea, set a minimum (or fixed) size for the widgets, and hide the scroll bars (or use [`setVerticalScrollBarPolicy()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractscrollarea.html#verticalScrollBarPolicy-prop) or [`setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractscrollarea.html#horizontalScrollBarPolicy-prop) with `Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff`. Note: when using layouts, it's impossible to have "packed" widgets, as basic layout managers always prevent that.

Comment: @musicamante - That's about how I am thinking so far.  I'm stuck here: How to tell whether a widget is fully viewed?  I'm thinking to pack widgets in a scrolling area, until I get 1 widget that's partially, or not, visible, then pop it out and call it a day.  But this will require me to have an approach to test "is widget fully visible?".

Comment: @hyde - is it possible to create a custom layout in PySide?

Comment: https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython/overviews/layout.html#how-to-write-a-custom-layout-manager

Comment: QRect has methods for checking if one rect contains or intersects another.

Comment: @caveman I really don't see why you'd need to do that: the scroll area will automatically do that, you don't have to hide or show ***nothing*** (and doing it would be wrong, by the way).

Comment: @musicamante - I'm trying to create a page flipper instead of a scroller.  I disagree with the philosophy of page scrolling as I find it sub-optimal.  Page scrolling eventually causes the user to read in series (he/she ends up scanning at the bottom edge as he is scrolling).  While a page flipper allows maximum information gain per pixel upon a single key press.   Even if you press the "space" bar to scroll page-wide, it is sub-optimal as some boundary-widgets will be half visible.  Ultimately, my goal is to create a multi-column page flipper UI.

Comment: @caveman at some point you'd need to use a similar approach any way (consider the issue of window resizing): using a scroll area does ***not*** mean that you're forced to use it as such (nor ask it to the user), but thay you can use a well defined API instead of reinventing the wheel.

Comment: @musicamante - Not sure I understand your point.  Do you suggest that I may use a scrolling area as a working ground to push/pop widgets, without necessarily scrolling in it?  E.g. perhaps just to add widgets to test whether they're fully visible (if not, then pop them)?

Comment: @musicamante I think the core thing is, OP doesn't want clipped items at the edges of the viewport. Scroll area doesn't really do that.

Comment: @caveman So I think you could also just use `QVBoxLayout ` or `QGridLayout`, but re-build it every time window is resized, and when next item would go beyond bottom of parent widget, stop adding. And keep extra widgets hidden if they need yo exist even when not visible.

Comment: You *may* need to call `polish()` 
or something between adding widgets to get correct size hints etc.

Comment: @hyde yes, it can, by using [`setViewportMargins()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractscrollarea.html#setViewportMargins), considering the geometry of the "last" fully visible widgets on the bottom and right margin.

Comment: @musicamante - How does `setViewportMargins` help?  I tried `self.scroll.setViewportMargins(50,50,50,50)`, and what I saw is just some thick margins that still allowed for showing half-visible widgets.

Comment: @caveman As written above, you have to consider the geometry of the last visible widget and set the margins according to that. Suppose that the last fully visible widget has its bottom at 20px from the edge of the scroll area, you'll then use `setViewportMargins(0, 0, 0, 20)`. In this way the window will always have the proper size, and widgets that don't "fit" the area will be "hidden". Then you only have to hide the scroll bars (and ignore wheel events), and eventually manage the focus chain to properly "scroll" programmatically and update the bottom margin accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code. It does not rely on `QVBoxLayout` but it basically does the same as this layout. It hides the child widgets which are outside of the area. There are no partially visible widgets.

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets

class Container(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    _spacing = 5

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        y = self._spacing
        for i in range(40):
            button = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Button" + str(i + 1), self)
            button.move(self._spacing, y)
            y += button.sizeHint().height() + self._spacing

    def resizeEvent(self, event):
        super().resizeEvent(event)
        for child in self.children():
           if isinstance(child, QtWidgets.QWidget):
               child.resize(self.width() - 2 * self._spacing, child.height())
               child.setVisible(child.geometry().bottom() < self.height())


app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
w = Container()
w.resize(500, 500)
w.show()
app.exec_()
```

Note that is in fact does not **add** nor **remove** widgets dynamically, this would be much more code and it would probably be very depending on your specific use case. Moreover it feels as a premature optimization. Unless you **really** need it, do not do it.

UPDATE:
I experimented with the code above and proposed some improvements. I especially wanted to make it responsive to changes in child widgets. The problem is that if the child widget changes it size, the parent container must be re-layouted. The code above does not react in any way. To make it responsive, we need to react to `LayoutRequest` event. Note that in the code below, I have created three types of buttons - one add a line to itself, other increases font size, and yet another decreases font size.

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets

def changeFontSize(increment):
    font = QtWidgets.QApplication.font()
    font.setPointSize(font.pointSize() + increment)
    QtWidgets.QApplication.setFont(font)

class Container(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    _spacing = 5
    _children = []  # maintains the order of creation unlike children()

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        for i in range(100):
            child = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self)
            child.installEventFilter(self)
            # these are just to test various changes in child widget itself to force relayout
            r = i % 3
            if r == 0:
                text = "New line"
                onClicked = lambda state, w=child: w.setText(w.text() + "\nclicked")
            elif r == 1:
                text = "Bigger font"
                onClicked = lambda: changeFontSize(1)
            elif r == 2:
                text = "Smaller font"
                onClicked = lambda: changeFontSize(-1)

            child.setText(text)
            child.clicked.connect(onClicked)
            self._children.append(child)

    def resizeEvent(self, event):
        super().resizeEvent(event)    
        self._relayout() 
           
    def event(self, event):
        if event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.LayoutRequest:
            self._relayout()
            
        return super().event(event)

    def _relayout(self):
        y = self._spacing
        for child in self._children:
            h = child.sizeHint().height()
            child.move(self._spacing, y)
            child.resize(self.width() - 2 * self._spacing, h)
            y += h + self._spacing
            child.setVisible(y < self.height()) 

app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
w = Container()
w.resize(500, 500)
w.show()
app.exec_()
```

This code is satisfactory, however it is not perfect. I have observed that when the container is being re-layouted and some of the child widgets will change its visibility state, re-layouting is called again. This is not needed but I have not discovered how to prevent it.

Maybe there is some better way...

Comment: Interesting.  I can move on from here.  Thanks a lot.  I have a question: Is the `resizeEvent` fired immediately after `__init__` returns?  If so, why?  Because, the way I understand it, it seems to me that `__init__` is creating 40 widgets, then hoping that a resize event will come so that excess widgets will be made invisible, but I think that `resizeEvent` is fired only when a resize happens, and I'm not sure if, initially, returning `__init__` will fire the event.

Comment: Is calling `polish()` useful here as hyde suggested in comments above?  If not, any reason?

Comment: @caveman I created the most simple example. Of course you can improve it further. Btw. when the widget is created and not showed, then it does not matter whether the child widgets are visible or not. And before it is frst displayed, it will always be resized. So initialization of visibility should be OK. With polishing, you will need to experiment... This example relies on the fact that the sizeHint() (its height) does not change. So further improvements are your homework. :)

Comment: @caveman I updated the answer to make it a more generic.